# Can Silent Speech be used with invisible targets and ones behind full cover?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, targeting, halfling, telepathy

I'm thinking of creating a party of twin Ghostwise Halfling Rogue. They can infiltrate a castle and communicate with each other silently.

If one of them went invisible, can the other use Silent Speech to speak to him? **What if the invisible halfling position is already known, such as standing beside the speaker?** Can it be used if they are separated by walls, and they already pinpointed each other position by knocking on the walls?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Silent Speech doesn't require vision of the target.

Silent Speech, unlike other forms of telepathy in 5e, doesn't require you to see the creature you wish to communicate with.

> **Silent Speech.** You can speak telepathically to any creature within 30 feet of you. The creature understands you only if the two of you share a language. [...] *(SCAG, 110)*

Compare this, for example, to other types of telepathy in 5e, such as the warlock's Awakened Mind.

> Starting at 1st level, your alien knowledge gives you the ability to touch the minds of other creatures. You can communicate telepathically with any creature **you can see** within 30 feet of you. [...] *(PHB, 110)*

If something requires vision or line of sight, it states so. Silent Speech doesn't, so you should be able to speak to a creature that you know is there, even if invisible or separated by a wall, using Silent Speech.